# Transactions are not getting rollbacked with HikariCP

Tags: java, mysql, connection, rollback, hikaricp

I am using `HikariCP` for connection pooling. I have tried setting `autoCommit` to both true and false. Still my transactions are not getting
rollbacked when an exception occur.

I have tried the same with `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`. Transactions are getting rollbacked properly with this datasource but
not when `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource` is configured.

I'm using MySQL InnoDB database engine.

**Edit:**

```
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
public class AServiceImpl {


@Override
public SomeDTO signUpUser(SomeDTO someDTO) throws Exception {

Company company = addCompany();
User user = addUser();
------------

}

private Company addCompany()

try{
    return companyRepository.addCompany();
} catch(PersistenceException e){
//throws exception
 }
} 

@Override
public User addUser()
try{
return userRepository.addUser();
}catch(PersistenceException e){
//throws exception
}
}
```

Here, exception occurs at `addUser` method and records inserted through `addCompany` method isn't rollbacked

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="100" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="900000" />
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="2000" />
        <property name="minimumIdle" value="20" />
        <property name="maxLifetime" value="1800000" />
        <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="60000" />
        <property name="autoCommit" value="false" />

        <property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="prepStmtCacheSize">300</prop>
                <prop key="prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</prop>
                <prop key="cachePrepStmts">true</prop>
                <prop key="useServerPrepStmts">true</prop>
                <prop key="useLocalSessionState">true</prop>
                <prop key="useLocalTransactionState">true</prop>
                <prop key="rewriteBatchedStatements">true</prop>
                <prop key="cacheResultSetMetadata">true</prop>
                <prop key="cacheServerConfiguration">true</prop>
                <prop key="elideSetAutoCommits">false</prop>
                <prop key="maintainTimeStats">true</prop>
                <prop key="useLocalTransactionState">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
    </bean>

HikariCP version: 3.1.0 
JDK version : 1.8.0_162 
Database : MySQL InnoDB
MySQLJDBCDriver version : 5.1.31
```

Looking for some solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your relevant code where you're failed to rollback. Which framework are you using. Are you calling method inside the same class?

Comment: What do you think will perform the rollback? None of the technologies tagged handles that by itself. Are you using JTA or some other transaction management? Do you understand what you're doing?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn : I'm using Spring framework. I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Have you rethrow exception in your `catch` clause yet?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn : There's no issue with the code. I just given a sample code. The same is working fine with `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`

Comment: Can you show your hikari configuration and what hikari version you are using

Comment: @user7294900 : I have updated my question with the hikari configuration.Please have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that transactions are *not* being rolled back?

If `autoCommit=false` *and* the transaction state is dirty, [HikariCP will automatically rollback](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/ProxyConnection.java#L239) on `Connection.close()`.  If debug logging is enabled, you should see it logged.  If you do not see the log message, that implies that Spring is explicitly calling `rollback()` (or `commit()`) before calling `close()` -- as I would expect with the annotation above.

Comment: *How do you know that transactions are not being rolled back*? - 

Records are getting inserted into the tblCompany which is the first query in the transaction even after exception is thrown from the second query. So as You have mentioned ,`rollback()` is getting called before `close()` method and the flag `useLocalTransactionState` was `true`. So rollback doesn't happen. Once the control reaches this method , `isCommitStateDirty` is set to false. So even if `close()` method is reached ,rollback won't happen there also. ..Solution : set `useLocalTransactionState` to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `useLocalTransactionState` to `false` and see whether it makes a difference.

Attention: your configuration is currently setting this property twice! Remove one of the duplicate lines with `<prop key="useLocalTransactionState">true</prop>` and then change the remaining one to set the property to `false` instead of `true`.

Why I recommend this: I just spent a day trying to figure out why my transactions do not get rolled back. I found out that it's connected to the `useLocalTransactionState` property. If I set `useLocalTransactionState` to `true` my transactions do not get rolled back although, my debugging and [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) clearly show that a rollback is performed by my transaction manager.

There is the MySQL Connector/J bug [#75209](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75209) that describes something similar. Although that bug claims to be fixed with MySQL Connector/J v5.1.40, I can still see similar behaviour for v5.1.40 and v8.0.13.

Comment: In your case, it might actually be due to #75209, since you are using v5.1.31.